# Use enviroment variable inside sh script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, terraform, jenkins-groovy

I am trying to access the `env` in an `sh` script but unable to access them. I want to append the value of `env` to the sh script. As I want to run a specific terraform module so I want to append the value in front of terraform apply and terraform output

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    parameters {
        choice(
                choices: 'first\nsecond\n',
                description: 'number',
                name: 'name'
        )
    }
    stages {
        stage("set env variable"){
            steps{
                script{
                    if ( params.name== 'first'){
                        env.output = "first_dns"
                        env.module = "module.first"
                    }
                    else if (params.name == 'second'){
                        env.output = "second_dns"
                        env.module = "module.second"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage('Deployment') {
            steps {
                script {
                  sh '''#!/bin/bash
                    terraform apply -target=${env.module} -auto-approve
                    terraform output {env.output}
                    '''
                    }
                }
            }      
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Jenkins is injecting the environment variables but you need to access them how you would in a normal shell script.
Because of the single quotes, the variables will be evaluated at run time of the shell script and it won't be able to find those variables.
This should work:

```
stage('Deployment') {
  steps {
     script {
       sh '''#!/bin/bash
       echo ${module}
       echo ${output}
       '''
     }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, if you use double quotes, what you wrote will also work.
In that way, jenkins will substitute those values before executing.

```
stage('Deployment') {
  steps {
     script {
       sh """#!/bin/bash
       echo ${env.module}
       echo ${env.output}
       """
     }
  }
}
```